# Difference between AjuA and ajuA in biosynthesis

Tags: nomenclature, biosynthesis

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. In the following figure, you can find *ajuA* and *AjuA* for example.

I do understand that the lower-case ones are the genes. The arrows indicate the direction of transcription. However, what is the difference to the upper-case *AjuA*? The text speaks of subunits. How are the two related? When do I speak of *ajuA* and when would I be talking about *AjuA*?

I would also be happy if you could point me in the direction of some literature about the basics of this kind of notation.

PS: I do understand the mechanisms of the biosynthetic route and am familiar with the different domains in the modules as well as PKS and NRPS modules.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the nomenclature:

> Bacteria: Gene symbols are typically composed of three lower-case, italicized letters that serve as an abbreviation of the process or pathway in which the gene product is involved (e.g., *rpo* genes encode RNA polymerase). To distinguish among different [but related genes], the abbreviation is followed by an upper-case letter (e.g., the *rpoB* gene encodes the β subunit of RNA polymerase). Protein symbols are not italicized, and the first letter is upper-case (e.g., RpoB).

[[source]](http://www.biosciencewriters.com/Guidelines-for-Formatting-Gene-and-Protein-Names.aspx)

You can check out the Wikipedia article on [Gene Nomenclature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_nomenclature) for more information.

Comment: But what is the relationship between gene and protein symbols? Can they be used interchangeably? The paper talks about AjuK containing a module, while "genes _ajuK_ and _ajuL_ encode the first two biosynthetic proteins". Does that mean, the gene _ajuK_ for example encodes the protein AjuK, which in turn does biosynthetic stuff?

Comment: @basseur *"Does that mean, the gene ajuK for example encodes the protein AjuK, which in turn does biosynthetic stuff?"* Without reading the paper, yes that's what it sounds like.